# Debian : Cron job not firing

Tags: bash, debian, cron

I have a cron-job, which is just a script, clearing directories, which accumulate files over time. Unfortunately, it is not firing. Any idea why. I have created the cron-job using cronmaker.com.

How do I know it was not fired, because it is set to fire every night, yet there are old files in it.

output of crontab -e

```
0 0 3 1/1 * ? * ./home/deploy/scripts/clearzip.sh
```

Thank you for your help.

Script contents :

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /media/attachment/zip/*.*
rm -rf /home/deploy/excel/*.*
rm -rf /home/deploy/pdf/*.*
```

Comment: what you trying to achieve? simply everynight at midnight?

Comment: There's a difference between 'not firing' and 'firing but doing the wrong thing, or maybe nothing at all'.

Comment: @EightBitTony : If I execute the clearzip.sh manually, then its working, just not automatically. But I have made changes as per Stephens answer.

Comment: @WeareBorg I suspect Stephen's answer is correct, however, running a job manually doesn't mean it will work under `cron`.  `cron` has a minimal environment, where the PATH for example is very different to your normal shell.  Search this site for stuff runs manually but not under `cron`.  My point was that you can't just assume it's not running because it doesn't do anything - you can solve that by adding logging to the script (if there's none at present) or by checking the `cron` daemon logs.

Comment: @EightBitTony : I have updated the post to include the contents of the script, like I said, it's just a cleanup script to delete unnecessary files. I checked syslog, but because our providers also log on that, its difficult to find information in that file.

Comment: Make it a habit to use full executable path names in scripts that (also) are called from `cron`, with `rm` you're probably safe, but not finding things e.g. in /usr/local/bin is the primary cause for things not being found. Also use absolute paths for your cron entry, yours starts with a `.` and only works if cron starts executing your command in `/` and not e.g. in your home directory.

Comment: @Anthon : Yes, that's why I also changed the script to what Stephen said. But why is cronmaker giving cron expressions which wont properly work is what I can't understand.

Comment: @WeareBorg cronmaker is just trying to bank in on the cron name with their website hoping to attract people and getting them to use quartz, but primarily to get donations. If they would call it quartzmaker 99.9% of the people (like) you working with cron would never ever visit their website.

Comment: @Anthon : Unfortunately, I went on that site from SO, where users on SO recommended to try cronmaker.com

Comment: @WeareBorg that is why you can downvote on the [so] and [se] sites, the answer with the link to cronmaker.com didn't help you, so you downvote. I have also see it happen that an answer was  essentially little more than an advertisement, in that case I flag a post. In both cases you are not helped, but someone coming after you might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) uses [Quartz cron triggers](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.2/html/qtz-all/#page/quartz-scheduler-webhelp%2Fco-trg_crontriggers.html%23), which add a couple of non-standard fields (for seconds and years). You should drop the first and last fields for standard `cron`, use `*` instead of `?`, and remove the leading `.` from your command:

```
0 3 1/1 * * /home/deploy/scripts/clearzip.sh
```

will run every day at 3am. More idiomatically,

```
0 3 * * * /home/deploy/scripts/clearzip.sh
```